# I want to build an array in javascript using text from a user input field in html and have it appear inside a p tag with .push. HOW?

Tags: arrays, input, methods, push

This is my HTML Sheet--

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
         <label for= "like">Name Choices</label><br>
         <input type="text" id="like" placeholder= "Enter a name selection">
         <button>Add to list</button>
         <p id="nameList"></p>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
--------------------------------
And this is my javascript code/sheet:

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const para = document.querySelectorAll('p');
let bNames = document.getElementById('like');
const arr = [bNames];

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let bNames = inputs.value;
  let result = `arr.push[bNames]`;
  p.push.innerHTML = ("like");
  return result;

})

-----
```

I can input names, but when I click submit, the text disappears and I am left with an open space and No Array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>INject</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="like">Name Choices</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="like" placeholder="Enter a name selection" />
    <button onclick="enterParagraph()">Add to list</button>
    <p id="nameList"></p>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  const arr = [];
  function enterParagraph() {
    const field = document.querySelector("#like").value;
    arr.push(field);
    document.querySelector("#nameList").innerHTML = arr;
  }
</script>
```

From you code i can guess you don't have much understanding of javascript. I'd recommend you first learn a bit more about javascript. MDN has an excellent guide to JavaScript.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript

Comment: I am a student at this point. But I just tried your edits. Wow. Thank your for assistance. This was racking my brain. Will utilize the resource you mentioned. Thanks again for the save.

Comment: If the answer helped you make sure to mark it as accepted answer so that it can help others too.
Happy Coding :)